# Cannot call callback functions on setState in componentDidMount ?? - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following simple code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this._fetchData();
  }

  _fetchData() {
    let url = UrlFormatter() + '/api/v1/blogs/';

    $.get(url, (result) => {
      if (result.status === 401) {
        this.setState({
          error: 'Your session has expired. We cannot load data.',
        });
      } else {
        console.log('obvs here');
        this.setState({
          error:             null,
          data:              result,
        }, () => {
          console.log('dasddsa');
          this._setUpPostCollapseStatus();
        });
      }
    }).fail((response) => {
      this.setState({
        error: 'Could not fetch blogs, something went wrong.'
      });
    });
  }
```

If we investigate the console we see:

`obvs here`

But we never see: `dasddsa`, now either this is a bug, or you cant call a callback function on `setState` in `componentDidMount` - Or I fail at ES6.

**Ideas?**

Comment: is the component rerendering correctly or is there an error occuring while rerender? because the callback is only excecuted after the rerender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, I wasn't able to replicate this; not sure if this'll be helpful, but here's an example of resolving a promise in `componentDidMount` and using the `setState` callback:

http://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/dXWQAr?editors=0011

**promise**

```
const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Fetched data!')
  }, 2000)
})
```

**component**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Mounting...');
    promise
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data }, () => {
          console.log('Data loaded')
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      })
  }
```

**console**

```
> "Mounting..."
> "Data loaded"
```